# Cells stuck at running after running after finding symbolic eigenvalues of a 4x4 matrix

Tags: matrix, bugs, eigenvalues, algebra, version-13.2

I used the code below to calculate the eigenvalues of a 4x4 matrix symbolically.

```
M = ( {
    {P, Q, 0, 0},
    {R, S, Subscript[\[Theta], 1], Subscript[\[Theta], 2]},
    {0, 0 , P - \[Lambda], Q},
    {\[Sigma] Subscript[\[Theta], 1], \[Sigma] Subscript[\[Theta], 2],
      R, S - \[Lambda]}
   } );
x = Eigenvalues[M];
e1 = ToRadicals[x[[1]]] // StandardForm;
```

The code runs as expected, and the output is shown properly. However, after running the said cell, running any other cells result in the kernel showing **Running** indefinitely. For example, I ran the code:

```
1 + 1
```

Immediately after the previous block and the kernel showed *Running* indefinitely.

I am using MMA 13.2 in Ubuntu 22.10.

Comment: No problem on 13.1 on windows 10. did you try everything again from clean kernel? may be there is a bug on Ubuntu?

Comment: I do not exactly know what you mean by clean kernel. When I restart MMA, everything runs normally, but as soon as I run this code, the next cell to be run gets stuck on running. Is there something else I should have done to get a "Clean Kernel"?

Comment: clean kernel means typing `Quit[]` in the cell before. But if you did this after starting MMA, then that is the same thing basically. It could be a bug. I do not know since I do not have Mathematica on Ubuntu to try.

Comment: After the cell gets stuck on running, I have tried the Stop Kernel -> Local followed by Start Kernel -> Local. Then reran just the 1+1 cell. That still did not help. The cell still got stuck at running. Aren't doing these two things the equivalent?

Comment: typing `Quit[]` in a cell on its own, is the same as `Evaluation->Quit Kernel` using the menu.  If you do this **before** typing `1+1` in a new cell and it still hangs, then something is very wrong.

Comment: Just tried it, and the cell with just `Quit[]` in it itself gets stuck in running. However, quitting and restarting the kernel via the evaluation menu after the first code results in succeeding cells being run normally.

Comment: humm. Are you sure the first command with the `Eigenvalues` did actually finish? it looks like it is still running. Does the notebook at the top says "running" before you type `1+1` in new cell?

Comment: Yes I checked, the Eigenvalues block did indeed complete and the kernel *does not* say running before I run the `1+1` code

Comment: Although not related to the primary problem: your `e1` has the `Head` of `StandardForm`. Do not include formatting in variable definitions. The definition should be `(e1 = ToRadicals[x[[1]]]) // StandardForm;` The parentheses isolate the format command from the definition.